# UISearchBar - Show all rows when no search text

Tags: uisearchbar

I am using a UISearchBar with two scope buttons. I want to use the scope buttons to filter the rows even when there is NO search text. Right now the rows are only filtered when there is search text. It appears from debugging that the searchResultsTableView has a zero frame size.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out...

**In ViewController.h file:**

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
{
    UISearchBar *searchBar;
    UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *friendsArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *searchResults;

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope;
```

**And in ViewController.m file:**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

        self.friendsArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Napoli",@"Juventus",@"Inter",@"Milan", @"Lazio",@"Real Madrid",@"Barcelona",@"Villareal",@"Valencia",@"Deportivo",@"Manchester City",@"Manchester United",@"Chelsea",@"Arsenal",@"Liverpool", nil];
        self.searchResults = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 44)];
    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];

    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [self.searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [self.friendsArray count];

    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.friendsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }


    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - searchDisplayControllerDelegate


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    self.searchResults = [self.friendsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to do that, save an array with all data.
In textDidChange when searchText.length == 0 show all copy instead the array of search results

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        tableSource = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.homeSheets.data];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        return;
    }

    ...
}
```